# Semidirect Product variations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Is there two semidirect products of order $16$ with $C_2$ normal subgroup?

How many groups of the form $C_4 \times C_2$ : $C_2$ are there ?

Is it one expression for two groups ? or more?

Comment: You are looking for maps $C_4 \times C_2 \to \mathrm{aut}(C_2)$. So ask yourself what $\mathrm{aut}(C_2)$ is.

Comment: could you explain more ? what do you mean?

Comment: You should probably add to your question the definition of semi-direct product you're most comfortable with if you don't understand my comment.

Comment: ok thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

A semi direct product $A\rtimes B$ is given by a group action of $B$ onto $A$, or equivalently by a group homomorphism $B\to \mathrm{Aut}(A)$, where $\mathrm{Aut}(A)$ is the group of automorphisms of $A$. Moreover, the semi direct product is isomorphic to $A\times B$ if the action is trivial.

In your case, the normal subgroup $A$ is of size $2$, so there are two elements, one is the identity and the other of order $2$. You cannot switch them, so $\mathrm{Aut}(A)$ is trivial. Hence, $A\rtimes B=A\times B$ for each group $B$, if $A$ is of size $2$.

If you try to do the converse, so take $A=C_4\times C_2$ and $B=C_2$, then you need to find an action of $B$ onto $A$.

Answer (score 1):

There are two groups with structure description $(C_4\times C_2)\rtimes C_2$ whose Gap Ids are $(16,3)$ and $(16,13)$. You may see [this](http://buzzard.ups.edu/courses/2012spring/projects/clausen-groups-16-ups-434-2012.pdf) for more detail.